# C/unix Sockets: Segmentation fault (core dumbed) due to char pointer(?)

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, pthreads

(maybe a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643368/c-socket-segmentation-fault-core-dumped) question, but I find it quite hard to pinpoint my problem myself, so if the answer here is even close to identical to the other question, I'll try to delete the question)

I want to make a client and a server program (with multiple clients using pthreads), where each client sends N numbers (input by the user) to the server, and the server returns the average of these numbers with an "ok message" if average>10, else the server returns a "not ok message".

After the client prints the results of the server, the user is asked if he wants to enter a new number sequence for its average.

Here is where I got so far:

Client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define SOCK_PATH "avg_socket"

    int main(void)
    {
        int i, s, t, len, done;
        int numofintegers;
        int yesorno;
        int average, avg;
        char *sequencecheck;

        struct sockaddr_un remote;
        char str[100];

        if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("socket");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Trying to connect...\n");

        remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
        strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
        len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);
        if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) {
            perror("connect");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Connected.\n");

        done = 0;
        do {
            printf("Give the number of integers:");
           fscanf(stdin, "%d", numofintegers);

            send(s, &numofintegers, sizeof(numofintegers), 0);

            int ar[numofintegers];

            for(i=0;i<numofintegers;i++)
            {
                printf("Give the number %d \n", i+1);
                printf("> ");
                fscanf(stdin, "%d", ar[i]);
            }

            send(s, &ar, numofintegers*sizeof(int), 0);

            sequencecheck=recv(s, str, 100, 0);     

            if(strcmp(sequencecheck, "Sequence Ok"))
            {
                average=recv(s, avg, sizeof(avg), 0);
                printf("Average of numbers: %d", avg);
            }


           send(s, &yesorno, sizeof(yesorno), 0);

           if(!yesorno)
       {
                done=1;
        }

         } while (!done);

        close(s);

        return 0;
    }
```

I keep getting segmentation faults from the client side and I guess a pointer went rogue somewhere here `sequencecheck=recv(s, str, strlen(str), 0);` .

But as I said above, I have a hard time finding the actual problem.

Which are the problems in my code?

Comment: Beg your pardon? I mean the problems of the char pointer in my code.

Comment: Sorry those are the rules. There's too much code (check the scrollbars!) I'm sure we don't need to read your whole code for this. check what a [mcve] is. And learn how to use a debugger. It'll be helpful next time too.

Comment: I wanted to eliminate all possible kinds of misconception. I can delete the server part tho.

Comment: You must comeltely and correctly handle the result from system calls, especially recv().  Just because you ask for sizeof(int) bytes does not mean you get them all in one call.   Note well that 'n = recv(so, numofintegers, sizeof(numofintegers), 0);' cannot load the 'numofintegers' argument with anything because it's passed by value, (needs a '&').

Comment: @Coursal much better. I reverted downvote & close vote

Comment: ouch, `str` seems to be uninitialized. so `sequencecheck=recv(s, str, strlen(str), 0);   ` cannot work

Comment: @ThingyWotsit changed it to  'n = recv(so, &numofintegers, sizeof(numofintegers), 0);', still core dumped but the smallest things can lead to the solution. thank you.

Comment: Oh - I didn't get as far as the client code :)  Seems that the others have found a few probs there too..

Comment: Yup - 'sequencecheck=recv(s, str, strlen(str), 0);' is fully stuft, for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
        sequencecheck=recv(s, str, strlen(str), 0);
```

You haven't assigned any value to `str` yet, so it doesn't point to a string. So calling `strlen` makes no sense -- what string are you trying to get the length of?

I strongly urge you to stop coding and start *documenting* the network protocol you plan to use. Document it at the byte level. Define what a "message" is and specify how they're delineated.

You can look at documentation for existing protocols (like HTTP, SMTP, or IRC) to get an idea. Obviously, yours doesn't have to be that detailed, but it should specify how the server and client start a connection, decide where messages begin and end, and tear down the connection.

It should provide enough details so that two different people could implement the server and client using just the protocol documentation and be able to exchange data.

Comment: str should either be the "ok message" or the "not ok message" that I had on the server code previously here and now here [link] (https://pastebin.com/BpFug8tT)

Comment: Where do you think you assign `str` a sensible value? You pass a nonsense value to both `recv` and `strlen`.

Comment: exactly why I didn't answer. You have to know which size to read from. The code is unfixable as is.

Comment: @Coursal How can `strlen(str)` know the length of the message before it receives it?

Comment: @Coursal The length you pass to `recv` should be the size of the input buffer that you allocated to hold the message, not the size of the message that was sent. But you never allocated the input buffer.